# \begin{frame}[<+->] and \section{...} results in multiple sections

Tags: beamer, sectioning

I am writing my first presentation slides with Latex using beamer.

But I run into a silly problem. It is similar to the code below:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[<+->]
\section{First Section}
\begin{itemize}
\item <1-> First item
\item <2-> Second item
\item <3-> Third item
\item <4-> Forth item
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This results in four sections named `First Section`. How can you tell Latex that this is only one section?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Put the section outside the frame

Comment: This is a duplicate... let me see if I can find it.